# Using a custom swift framework from a swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I have my main project in swift and Im trying to add one more swift project(Framework project) as a dependency project to my main project. When Im trying to access framework methods inside the main project its giving me a compile error saying "Expected declaration". But I'm able to instantiate objects from the framework classes. Only Im not able to access methods.

Here's the link for the sample project. Please make sure you run the project in Xcode6 beta 4.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qrtlibw813c53ub/AAAfBzOZh99eUWhvRK5YfG8va

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that this code is on the class level, outside of a function or method:

```
let temp: TesterClass = TesterClass()
temp.testMethod() // heres the compile error
```

If you move that for example into

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    let temp: TesterClass = TesterClass()
    temp.testMethod() // no compile error anymore ...
    // ...
}
```

it will work as expected.

If only the first line

```
let temp: TesterClass = TesterClass()
```

is on the class level, it defines a (constant) property `temp` which is initialized
with `TesterClass()`, this is allowed.